# How to apply style for css class using Material UI withStyle. WithStyle is not working

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, react-with-styles

Here is My Code

```
import { withStyles, MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

import classNames from 'classnames';


const styles = theme => ({
    myGridStyle:{
        '&:.my-row-selected':{
            backgroundColor:"#ff9900 !important"
        }
    },
});

<div className={myGridStyle}> 
    <div role="row" class="my-row-selected" style="height: 30px;"></div>
</div>
```

I am using non material ui component for grid I want to apply style through Material UI withstyle and theme, so I have added withStyle for my parent div and i want to apply style for child div and child CSS classes.

Comment: You are missing the `withStyles` HOC. Or you can use `makeStyles` hook

Answer (score 0):

You have several options, the newest is using the `makeStyles` hook, but you can use the `withStyles` HOC.

```
const styles = theme => ({
    myGridStyle: {
        '&:.my-row-selected':{
            backgroundColor:"#ff9900 !important"
        }
    },
});

function myGrid(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <div className={classes.myGridStyle}> 
        <div role="row" class="my-row-selected" style="height: 30px;"></div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default withStyles(styles)(myGrid);
```

https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/